# Solid and dashed line on the same series with nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to generate a multi-chart in NVD3 with a line which is solid and dashed after a specific value. The x-axis depends on time. I need have a dashed line (blue) for values in the future.

Now, I have this graph:

[image]

I need have something like this:

[image]

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: A simple approach, in terms of using CSS stroke-dasharray, would be to create two separate paths, one which ends on today's date, and one which starts on today's date, and style the second to use stroke-dasharray

Comment: Thanks, Tom, yes, I'm trying that, but I get two distinct series and two legends. Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/29ex53ad/10/